# 1980's - Lunar Police Procedural Novel(s)

Tags: story-identification, novel

Probably paperback originals, definitely published during the 1980s. American author. At least two volumes (I only read the first), possibly more.

The time is the near future and the Moon has been colonized. There is a Lunar police force & the main characters are a pair of hard-boiled detectives (possibly ex-NYPD; the story has a real 'New York City' vibe). Can't remember the plot, but the bad guys are the Mafia (so named) who are muscling in on the Final Frontier. The only other detail I can recall is that the MCs travelled by ballistic capsules that hurled them from one place to another.

Comment: A hard-boiled pair of detectives on the moon immediately reminded me of "Space Cops" by Diane Duane. I don't remember ballistic capsules (or the Mafia as such) though.

Comment: _[The Patchwork Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patchwork_Girl)_ by Larry Niven, featuring Gil "The Arm" Hamilton, was set on the Moon.  But it doesn't match otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these fit the bill - I am familiar with Niven's character & the 'Space Cops' covers do not seem familiar.

Comment: It sounds like "Space Precinct" (a Gerry Anderson live action show), which did have some novels published featuring ex-NYPD cop, but on a different planet, and looks like that was from the '90s.

Comment: I believe John Varley had at least a couple of short stories set among the police on the moon ; the ones I remember do not match, but perhaps he wrote others?